# Purpose of hard drive wiper software?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

> When you delete a file, Windows removes the pointer and marks the sectors containing the file’s data as available. From the file system’s point of view, the file is no longer present on your hard drive and the sectors containing its data are considered free space.
>
> However, until Windows actually writes new data over the sectors
>   containing the contents of the file, the file is still recoverable. A
>   file recovery program can scan a hard drive for these deleted files
>   and restore them. If the file has been partially overwritten, the file
>   recovery program can only recover part of the data. ([Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/125521/htg-explains-why-deleted-files-can-be-recovered-and-how-you-can-prevent-it/))

I was thinking of purchasing software to wipe a harddrive clean. But if the data has been overwritten than there is no way of it being recovered. So why not just copy past some large avi movie files until the harddisk is full and then deleting them instead of buying expensive software?

Comment: Instead of buying expensive software, why not use software that is both Free (libre) and free (gratis) - https://clonezilla.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: they're still useful for "Quick Erase" - otherwise, don't bother.

They came about mainly because you don't know *when* the OS is going to overwrite your file. There were always certain utilities (GNU has `shred`, for instance) that tried to guarantee an overwrite as part of a delete. Others tried to overwrite all your 'free space' to make sure that a deleted file was overwritten.

However, that's great, but... modern filesystems tend to try to allocate a file in one big continuous chunk, so if you delete a bunch of small files you'll get 'holes' in your allocation - so using a big movie file may not overwrite the little files. (Adding little files, will change that, but again, you're trying to *guarantee* you've clobbered the file.) Also it's entirely possible for a filesystem to allow you to "overwrite" a file by making a copy first and then you write your changes to that copy, then deleting the old file, making `shred` potentially a waste of time.

SSDs throw different wrenches into the machine; with things like sector remapping and flash wear-levelling, even the best "drive overwrite" utilities are fighting against the drive firmware's right to use spare sectors and different areas of the disk as error correction and longevity management.

The other answer at time of writing is correct - the modern best practice is to encrypt the entire drive (as filesystem-level encryption is only a small fraction of a performance penalty) and throw out the keys when the data is no longer needed.

If you want data to be kept private, the best three things to do, in this order, are:

- Don't save it in the first place
- Destroy the entire drive beyond all repair
- Encrypt the drive and lose the encryption keys

Drive Overwrite utilities were a nice way to clean up after the fact if you haven't encrypted the drive and wish to repurpose it. "Quick erase" just writes zero to all of the drive sectors, which is useful for repurposing a drive - the necessary unencrypted parts of the drive (GPT, /boot, EFI partition) will be wiped.

Anything else is a little much. I used to recommend the 3-pass (all 0's, all 1's, random garbage) for spinning-platter hard disks, but I wouldn't bother with an encrypted drive; just use the "Quick Erase" mode to zero the drive, and then re-purpose it.

Everything else is academic or overkill. 7 passes is the old US DOD standard and amazingly time consuming. The 35-pass method was the 'theoretical maximum' and it's absolutely pointless, because modern hard drives don't store data in the way that the paper expects them to be (iirc it was written before IDE, that's how old it is.)

Answer (score 1):

"Purpose of hard drive wiper software?"

Revenue for companies who make 'hard drive wiper software'.

Modern paradigm is just to encrypt the entire drive.
Remove the encryption keys & the data is gone forever. This can be as simple as just doing a quick format.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two primary purpose

1) Ensure the user/businesses that their data is permanently gone and not to be recovered by any data recovery/forensics method.
2) Compliance with the audit formalities.

With so many data breaches cases mushrooming, data is considered to be the goldmine in this digital age.